# Appropriate conversion of the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to do the plot using matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.
The problem is that I have data in the file, let's say data.dat, where
the first column is my X, the second column is my Y and the fird column
is C. The problem is that 'C' column should be an array--like.

My file looks like this

```
 1  4  5
 1  5  6
 1  6  7
 2  4  6
 2  5  7
 2  6  8
 3  4  7
 3  5  8
 3  6  9
```

But, for pcolormesh it should be

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
```

I tried like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.colors

A = np.loadtxt("data.dat")[:,0]
B = np.loadtxt("data.dat")[:,1]
C = np.loadtxt("data.dat")[:,2]

plt.pcolormesh(Delta, Vas, sigma, cmap='magma')
```

And I have no idea how to convert my file to aprropriate format for pcolormesh.